# How to remove PHP Warning : count() parameter must be an array that implements Countable

Tags: php, error-handling, count

I know this question has been asked many times, but I couldn't find anything that helped me.

My PHP code is returning a warning "Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable" when I try to count rows of a json_decode array, but the code works. How can I get rid of this warning ?

Here is the code (it makes anonymous fields in a database) :

```
//SQL Query to select my data and get "myVar"
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $l__myVar = json_decode($row["myVar"], true);
    $l__id        = $row["id"];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($l__myVar["node1"]["node1"]); $i++) {
        $l__myVar["node1"]["node1"][$i]["fname"] = SUBSTR(MD5(RAND()) . MD5(RAND()), 1, 6);
        $l__myVar["node1"]["node1"][$i]["lname"] = SUBSTR(MD5(RAND()) . MD5(RAND()), 1, 6);
    }

    $myVar  = json_encode($l__myVar);
    //Then I am doing my SQL update
}
```

As I said, it works and, for every node of the decoded JSON it does the  "SUBSTR(MD5(RAND()) . MD5(RAND()), 1, 6)", but I keep having the warning in my logs.

I don't want to disable all the warnings, but only find a way to correct this one.

Thanks !

**EDIT :**

Thanks to the comment, I finally managed to fix it. It looks like sometimes it was not an array but "NULL", so I added this :

```
if(is_array($l__myVar["node1"]["node1"])){
//Code
            }

elseif (!is_array($l__myVar["node1"]["node1"])) {
            continue;
        }
```

This way, PHP keep going on without displaying any error message.

Comment: perhaps `$myVar` should be `$l__myVar` in the `foreach`? `$myVar` is a JSON string, not an array.

Comment: Is there a reason why you name your variable this unreadble way? -> `$l__myVar`

Comment: by fixing it? o.O have you var_dump'd $myVar["node1"]["node1"] to see if it's an array?

Comment: And don't use count in `for` loop it will increase your execution time, get that count in $tempVarCount before `for`

Comment: @Nick Yes, sorry it's a mistake I made re-writting the code, I changed it in my question

Comment: @B001ᛦ just to change the name because these are information I should not post, so I prefered to change it :)

Comment: It seems some rows may not have a valid JSON value (or perhaps it's empty). You should add a `if (!is_array($l__myVar["node1"]["node1"])) continue;` after the `json_decode`

Comment: @Nick as it is in a while loop, it still try to do it on every row received by my SQL query, is it really necessary to add this ?

Comment: Without that test you will continue to receive warning messages. I guess it depends whether you want warning messages or fractionally slower code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that sometime `$l__myVar["node1"]["node1"]` is not an array,to avoid the warning use

```
if(is_array($l__myVar["node1"]["node1"])){
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($l__myVar["node1"]["node1"]); $i++) {
    $l__myVar["node1"]["node1"][$i]["fname"] = SUBSTR(MD5(RAND()) . MD5(RAND()), 1, 6);
    $l__myVar["node1"]["node1"][$i]["lname"] = SUBSTR(MD5(RAND()) . MD5(RAND()), 1, 6);
  }
}else{
   /*Your Code*/
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are right, and according to @treyBake comment, by dumping my data, sometimes I have the dump, and other time I have the error message I put in the "else"

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the count on $myVar, where as it seems this should be $l__myVar:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $l__myVar = json_decode($row["myVar"], true);
    $l__id        = $row["id"];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($l__myVar["node1"]["node1"]); $i++) {
        $l__myVar["node1"]["node1"][$i]["fname"] = SUBSTR(MD5(RAND()) . MD5(RAND()), 1, 6);
        $l__myVar["node1"]["node1"][$i]["lname"] = SUBSTR(MD5(RAND()) . MD5(RAND()), 1, 6);
    }

    $myVar  = json_encode($l__myVar);
    //Then I am doing my SQL update
}
```

From the code you have posted, $myVar isn't set til after count(); unless you have it set further up the script.

Comment: Yes sorry, I have it with my SQL query just before, I edited my question :)